# Fenomastic Mat on Jotashield Tex Ultra on powder-coated aluminium?

Tags: outdoor, repainting, humidity, uv-exposure

***Context.*** Hot, humid, and sunny outdoor climate.

***Input.*** Large shiny powder-coated aluminium panels with some dents in them.  This shiny finish makes the dents very visible.  The dents are not removable without throwing the panels away and bringing new ones (too expensive).

***Output.*** Finish the powder-coated aluminium panels such that they're mat and rough-textured in order to hide the imperfections.

***Plan.***

1. Sand and clean the powder-coated aluminium panel.
2. Roll this water-based [Jotashield Tex Ultra](https://www.jotun.com/Datasheets/Download?url=%2FTDS%2FTDS__4250__Jotashield+Tex+Ultra__Euk__GB.pdf) over the sanded powder-coated aluminium panel.  This should give it texture.
3. Roll this oil-based [Fenomastic Mat](https://www.jotun.com/Datasheets/Download?url=%2FTDS%2FTDS__39623__Fenomastic+Mat__Euk__GB.pdf) over the waster-based Jotashield Tex Ultra.

***Question.*** How durable/reliable is the plan to hide imperfections of flat powder-coated exterior aluminium panels in hot humid areas?  E.g. how long should I roughly expect the paint to not fall/crack/etc?

Comment: Do a test panel and subject to the conditions expected: full sun, rain, wind, hail, frost, snow and ice. Check performance and decide.

Comment: @SolarMike - How to subject it to those conditions?  By simply leaving it outdoor?  Any idea for how long?  And how to speed this experiment up?

Comment: Also, isn't there any general rules that are already learned by the painters with regards to which combinations work well with each other?  Can't these general rules help here without needing to run experiments (which may rediscover already-known facts).

Comment: Have you tried to remove the dents?  They don't seem to be big if you want to hide them with paint.

Comment: The mat stuff says for interial use, so probably won't last outside.  Both products seem to be made for cement type surfaces, so might not work well for your use.

Comment: Search the interwebz for "auto body dent removal". You find a bazillion videos showing you how to pull dents. Pick the method that seems most reasonable and within your skill set and actually pull the dents. You may or may not have to repaint, but you're planning on repainting anyway, so that's not an issue. If you don't feel comfortable doing the work yourself, find an auto body repair shop or a local metal worker that would be willing to take it on.

Comment: @FreeMan - too big of a dent.  The panels are bent.  Will require rewelding and buying new panels.